# Same parameter for different columns in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, odbc

I need to do a report in SSRS that gets a patient by *case number* **or** *surgery ID* name using the **same** textbox over ODBC.

So my query is `SELECT Name, DOB FROM Surgeries Where caseno = ? or sgid = ?`.
Since in ODBC, these are 2 separate parameters and I need to search only for one or the other. Is it possible? How my query can be optimized?

Comment: You can use a hidden parameter and default it to the visible parameter

Comment: Yes, but it gives 2 different rows, I need an either...or

Comment: aduguid's comment should be correct, your report will pass two parameters to the query but the value of these two parameters will be identical. I'll post an alterative answer in a moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I think that earlier comments should work fine, here is an alternative approach.

Please note that this is untested.

```
SELECT Name, DOB FROM Surgeries WHERE ? IN(caseno, sgid)
```

This also assumes that the parameter is NOT multi-valued.